# Showing error in rviz while trying gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using static transform publisher, I defined relationship between my robot and laser, i.e base_link-->laser

Then I created a fake robot odometry data which gives all required odometry using code from http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom
This links odom-->base_link

N then I - rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan
My frame chain is complete now map-->odom-->base_link-->laser

After that I am running a SICK LMS lidar.
But still when I run rviz and add map topic it just show error in map status and gives no result under map topic.
Can I have a clue where I might be going wrong ?
In terminal under gmapping node it is giving continuous warning that 100% of messages dropped so far..

Also under laser topic with fixed frame /map, I can see the laser data as per fake robot's movement. But again  here the status is going OK and error with frequency of 1, same as odometry refresh rate. Any idea why might that be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198947/showing-error-in-rviz-while-trying-gmapping/) by [Akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/19915/akash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-12-05**:
I would suggest hector_slam in your case. Did you use clock option with rosbag play ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, i was running rosbag with clock. Gmapping is working now when I plugged in the lidar.

---

Originally posted by [Akash](https://answers.ros.org/users/19915/akash/) with karma: 18 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0